# How to cut a substring on several occurrences of a pattern?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

After a thorough search on google and SO, I couldn't find this specific question on the tremendous amount of regex requests.

I have a single string that I want to parse in order to replace some substrings.

However, my case is a bit more complicated than a simple `str_replace` so I would need a structured version of my string.

For instance, let's take the value `value="There is __obj1__ and also __obj2__ in the house."`, with the pattern `__.*?__`.

I want to get something like `c("There is ", "obj1", "and also", "obj2", "in the house")` so I can act on all even indices.

Here is where I am so far. I'm struggling with the greediness of the regex, it is either too much or not enough. The matrix return type is not really a problem, I can `unlist(x[[1]][-1])` it.

```r
library(tidyverse)
value="There is __obj1__ and also __obj2__ in the house."
str_match_all(value, "(.*?)__(.*?)__(.*?)") #too greedy at the very end
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]                 [,2]         [,3]   [,4]
#> [1,] "There is __obj1__"  "There is "  "obj1" ""  
#> [2,] " and also __obj2__" " and also " "obj2" ""
str_match_all(value, "(.*)__(.*?)__(.*?)") #not greedy enough
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]                                  [,2]                          [,3]  
#> [1,] "There is __obj1__ and also __obj2__" "There is __obj1__ and also " "obj2"
#>      [,4]
#> [1,] ""
str_match_all(value, "(.*?)__(.*)__(.*?)") #not greedy enough
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]                                  [,2]        [,3]                    
#> [1,] "There is __obj1__ and also __obj2__" "There is " "obj1__ and also __obj2"
#>      [,4]
#> [1,] ""
str_match_all(value, "(.*?)__(.*?)__(.*)") #not greedy enough
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]                                                [,2]        [,3]  
#> [1,] "There is __obj1__ and also __obj2__ in the house." "There is " "obj1"
#>      [,4]                              
#> [1,] " and also __obj2__ in the house."
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Do you also consider using base R for this? Or do you want to use `stringr` by all means?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I find `stringr` way more elegant and maintainable (with value as the first argument) but any solution is welcome

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/SMPEka, does it work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, this is perfect! This is a much higher level of regexp than what I'm used to though. If you post it as an answer, would you mind explaining it a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
value <- "There is __obj1__ and also __obj2__ in the house."
library(stringr)
result <- stringr::str_match_all(value, "\\s*(.*?)__(.*?)__(.*?)(?=\\s*(?:__|$))")
result <- lapply(result, function(x) x[,-1])
result
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
     [,1]        [,2]   [,3]            
[1,] "There is " "obj1" " and also"     
[2,] ""          "obj2" " in the house."
```

The pattern is

```r
\s*(.*?)__(.*?)__(.*?)(?=\s*(?:__|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R2Q6Zn/1). Note you may even use possessive quantifiers with `\s*`, namely, `\s*+`, to speed up matching.

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `__` - a literal `__` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `__` - a literal `__` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:__|$))` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespaces followed with `__` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.